# Pick elements from a string and push in array

Tags: javascript, regex, lodash

I have a requirement like this.

Input string `Please choose one \n 1. optionA \n 2. optionB \n 3. optionC`

`Please choose one can be any text` can have any text in its place. From this `\n` till the `end of line` will have the exact same format including the spacing. The `optionA`, `optionB` and `optionC` are dynamic.

I want to push the `optionA`, `optionB` and `optionC` into an array. I have been trying it out with Regex and Javascript but wasn't successful. How do I do it?

I used `_.words` from lodash and regex `/\.(.*)\\/` . First of all the regex is not returning the word

Help me out

Comment: Can you show us what you've tried so far, and how it isn't working? Then we can steer you in the right direction to fixing it

Comment: Your regex seems to be looking for a literal backslash character; maybe you meant to look for the newline `\n`?

Answer (score 1):

Check this. **It will work only for text in the formatted you mentioned in your questions.**
 Since it is not fully clear whether you are using different strings or not, I give you this solution.
If you do so, leave a comment

```js
var str="This can be any string ending with\n 1. any_option \n 2. can_be_placed \n 3. without_space";
var opt=str.replace(/^[^\n]*\n\s?\d+.\s?/g,'');
opt=opt.replace(/\s?\n\s?\d+.\s?/g,',').split(',');
console.log(opt);
```

Comment: does not work if any of the numbered options have commas in them

Comment: yes. But generally option values didn't contain commas @AndrewWillems

Comment: The OP writes "The `optionA`, `optionB` and `optionC` are dynamic." which suggests to me that a common English punctuation mark like a comma could be encountered.

Answer (score 1):

The solution using `Array.prototype.match()` and `Array.prototype.map()` functions:

```js
var s = 'Please choose one \n 1. optionA \n 2. optionB \n 3. optionC',
    options = s.match(/\n \d+\. (\w+)/g).map(function(v){
        return v.trim().split(' ')[1];
    });

console.log(options);
```

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest using `split`:

```js
var input = 'Please choose one \n 1. optionA \n 2. optionB \n 3. optionC';
var options = input.split(/\s*?\n\s*\d+\.\s*/).slice(1);
console.log(options);
```

Comment: I believe the initial `/s*?` should just be `/s*`.

Comment: Yes it could be left out, but I think it is more time-efficient with the `?`, since it will not try to include the `\n` that follows in its first attempt, while without `?` it would first grab the `\n` in the `\s*`, only to discover that does not yield a match: it has to backtrack and then do it the correct way.

Comment: How does a non-greedy match of zero or more of anything at the start of a regex return anything? It clearly works, because your solution eliminates the spaces before the `\n`. But if zero of something is an option, and you're told to be non-greedy, why do you take anything?

Comment: A non-greedy match will take anything until the next pattern (`\n`in this case) matches.

Comment: Please forgive my persistence but I think you're teaching me something subtle but important about regex logic. [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp) writes that a non-greedy quantifier results in "...matching the minimum number of times". If what precedes is "zero or more of X", isn't the minimum of "zero or more" just "zero"?

Comment: The *"minimum number of times"* really means *"minimum number of times to achieve a complete match"*. If with zero times no complete match can be achieved, the system will try with 1, 2, 3, times until it can match the whole pattern. Without the `?` it would first try as many times as possible, and if the whole pattern does not match with that, it will decrease the number of times, until a complete match is found.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one ...

```js
var inputString = 'Please choose one\n 1. option_1 \n 2. option_2 \n 3. option_2';
var matchedList = inputString.match(/\b\w*[_]\w*\b/g);
console.log(matchedList);
```

Output `matchedList` array

["option_1", "option_2", "option_2"]

Comment: but it will not match option without underscore. He says that option_1 can be anything.